# Issue in exporting table visual to csv

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have an issue and I hope you ill be able to help me with your insights !
I've created a visual table in Power BI and I need to export it to csv, my issue is related to text fields (the original ones and those I've created via group by), they are splitted in the output while I need them to look excatly as in the visual.
I'm beggining with Power Bi, I hope soemone can help me 
Thank you in advance !

Comment: What do you mean? How does it look in the CSV compared to what you expect? Sample data is helpful.

Comment: Hello, could you please include an example of what the table looks like in Power BI and what it looks like when you export it to the CSV?